# execlp stops using socket to send the data

Tags: c++, bash, sockets, pipe

i'm creating a program to process some data remote.
So i use something like

cat file | ./client -i "machineip" -p "port" -c "command"

i can use the command as "base64 -d | tar -zvt" if i want to get the list inside my tar file.
I have those objects;

Sock.. is an object that implements the C socket.
RCVBUFSIZE  = 2000 and the size i use to send and get data
pid to know if i'm the child or the parent process

To do that i i'm using the pipe and fork.
the basic structure is:

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
if((pid=fork()) == -1) exit(-1);
if(pid == 0)
{
 while((recvMsgSize = sock->recv(echoBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE)){
  write(fd[1], echoBuffer, recvMsgSize);
 }
}
else pipeback(fd,sock)
```

So i can get the data and send from the parent to the child.
The client read from the stdin and send through the socket and the server read through the socket

The problem is in the pipeBack

```
void pipeback(int *fdRef, TCPSocket *sock){
 char *buffer = new char[2000];
 int size;
 close(fdRef[1]);
 dup2(fdRef[0], 0);
 close(fdrEf[0]);
 pipe(fout)
 if((pid = fork()) == -1)exit(-1);
 if(pid ==0){
  close(fout[0]);
  dup2(fout[1], 1);
  close(fout[1]);
  execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", "base64", NULL);
 }
 else{
  close(fout[1]);
  while((size = read(fout[0], buffer, 2000)) > 0){
   sock->send(buffer, size);
   write(fileno(stdout), buffer, size);
  }
 }
}
```

the problem is the line "execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", "base64", NULL);" if i use the cat on the fourth argument it works, if i use one ls -lahtr is shows me the files on the folder, so, works like a charm.
BUT, when i use base64 or uuencode... probably other commands it stops on the read line, and stops, dies, i used strace and the gdb to see what is happening.
I don't know what i need to do to debug this process.
So i created an separate program, only to read from the stdin and use the pipe to process on base64 or uuencode using the bash.
It works, i thing it is something with the socket or the time, but i dont have any ideas.
Sorry, but my English is not that gooood... XD.
Thanks for everything

NOTE:

I used strace, and i noticed when i use the base64 the pid stops and then it tries to read from the pid (already stopped).

Someone know how i can solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was

I send data and try to recv on the same block of code.
So i'm now using the select to wait until i have some data.